# How do I simplify f(5x)=2(5x)−f(8) to f(x) =

Tags: functions

Trying to simplify $f(5x)=2(5x)−f(8)$ to obtain an explicit form for the function $f$ (I don't think you could just divide like a normal equation).

Comment: It's a linear function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a new variable, $y=5x$. Now we have $f(y) = 2y - f(8)$. Plugging $y=8$ into this equation yields $2f(8) = 16$ so finally $f(y) = 2y - 8$ which is the same as $f(x) = 2x - 8$

Comment: Very nice! The same can be seen if we consider $x=8/5$ first, which tells use $f(8)=8$, and then replacing $y=5x$.